# How can I serve static index.html files in different dynamic folders on ngynx?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, static

I have a front-end app (builded as static) that would upload static packages, each one with its own index.html and assets as follows:

```
- index.html
- buildAssetsFolder/
- public/base/ <-- here the backend will upload the static packages
  |
  |__ foo1
  |   |
  |   |__ index.html
  |
  |__ foo2
  |   |
  |   |__ index.html
  |
  |__ foo(n+1)
      |
      |__ index.html
```

I'm able to upload do all the stuff I need in the admin section but when I try to access to
domain/public/base/foo1/index.html I get a 404

I tryed to configure nginx by using locations with regexp

```
server {
        server_name example.com;
        root   /www/mysite/;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        location ~/public/base/(?<foo>[^/]+)/ {
                root /var/www/html;
                index  index.html index.htm;
        }


        location /backend-service {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:123/backend-service;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location / {
             if (!-e $request_filename){
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
            }
        }


        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }

}
```

I've modified this block hundreds of times with no success, for example:

```
location ~/public/base/(?<foo>[^/]+)/ {
                alias /var/www/html/public/base/$foo;
                index  index.html index.htm;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem and want to share my experience in case you are facing a similar problem:

1. so the first thing: give permissions to your user and the nginx user on your web-foler:

```
    sudo chown -R "$USER":www-data /web-folder
    sudo chmod -R 0755 /web-folder
```

2. next thing at least in my case was that my backend was storing folders outside the base directory so instead of having `public/base/foo1` I was writing `public/foo1` so my routes would never work: in this case please before performing any modifications to the nginx server block make sure all your assets are located exactly where you want them to be.
3. the server block that finds the dynamic folder structure would be:

```
    location ~/public/base/(?<foo>[^/]+)/$ {
      try_files $uri /public/base/$foo/$1 $uri=404;
    }
```

consider that when you are using regexp patterns the location block must start with `~` then every regexp should be inside a pair of `()` in my case I'm using the regexp `(?<foo>[^/]+)` to get the dynamic folder name and use it later on my `try_files` statement. The `[^/]+` indicates to get every character excluding the `/` so we get `foo1`, and not `foo1/` and finally don't forget to end with `$`

then for the try_files statement:
`$uri` tells nginx to look for files inside a folder structure, there you will put your folder structure considering that the `root` directive would be precedent so if you have `root /usr/share/nginx/html` then this directive would search in that `root` the folder you specify, in my case would be something like `/usr/share/nginx/html`+`/public/base/$foo/$` (to give you an idea on how nginx is reading the try_files location if I'm not wrong).
Now `$foo` represents the matching result from the location block regexp `(?<foo>[^/]+)` and `$1` represents the rest of the url string that hasn't changed.

so wrapping all up:
if you try the url `http://example.com/public/base/foo1/index.html`you would get:

`$foo` = foo1

`$1` = index.html

and try_files will look for the following folder or file in your server:
`/usr/share/nginx/html/public/base/foo1/index.html`

I'm not an expert on nginx but that's what I've learned so far, there might be mistakes in my explanation so feel free to share your knowledge if you find I'm explaining something the wrong way.

anyways my app started to work and I'm happy, I hope I can share some of the joy of leaving frustration behind, happy coding!